# What is the correct tag for questions regarding Ubuntu release policy?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question about Ubuntu development policy, e.g. "[Does Ubuntu fix bugs in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062117/does-ubuntu-fix-bugs-in-lts-versions)".

What is the correct tag for such questions? Is this a question for Meta?

Comment: Meta is the right place to ask about tagging, but I'm pretty sure you got an answer on main.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be [release-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/release-management):

> Questions about the release procedures for a release, including policies, stable release updates, and distribution upgrades.